# Any alternative "bootstrap" gem that works on different prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Following some rails tutorials when I try to write a "bootstrap" app using 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1' I get this error message.

```
different prefix: "C:/" and "D:/{directory}/app/assets/stylesheets"
  (in D:/Projects/Rails/loginlayout/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
```

and in `stylesheets` directory my only one css file `/custom.css.scss` contains:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

I do realize that [its a bug](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/96) and I need to move my valuables to C:/ and it should work. But do we have any other alternative "gem" choice for that?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem through creating a symlink on the drive containing my Ruby installation to my project with the same folder structure.

E.g. my project is at "G:\project\web" so I created a symlink to that folder on "D:\project\web".

When I start my local development server from the project symlink mentioned (on D:\ instead of G:) bootstrap-sass works for the project without issues.